# Class variable as the counter of a For loop in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a class module called `MyClass`, with a public integer in it:

```
Public i as Integer
```

When I try to use this variable in a `For` loop like so:

```
Dim MyInstance as MyClass: Set MyInstance = New MyClass
For MyInstance.i = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print "Hello"
Next
```

I get the error: *Variable required. Can't assign to this expression*

I have consulted the [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/variable-required-can-t-assign-to-this-expression) but cannot see how it applies to my case. The relevant fragment is: "You tried to use a nonvariable as a loop counter in a `For...Next` construction. Use a variable as the counter." But `i` is a variable after all, and not a `Let Property` function or any other expression.

What is wrong with the code?

**EDIT:** I should point out that the reason I want my iterator to be part of the class is that I have multiple instances of the class, serving different purposes in my project, and there are multiple nested `For` loops for each instance of the class. Therefore it is worth having the iterators belong to their respective objects, say:

```
For Client.i = 1 To Client.Count
    For Order.i = 1 To Order.Count
        For Item.i = 1 To Item.Count
```

etc.

I have settled for the following workaround but am still not entirely satisfied with it:

```
For ciii = 1 To Client.Count
    Client.i = ciii ' Client.i is later used in the code
    For oiii = 1 To Order.Count
        Order.i = oiii
        For iiii = 1 To Item.Count
            Item.i = iiii
```

Comment: You cannot use MyInstance.i as the increment but you can use it as the terminator; e.g. For i = 1 To MyInstance.i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a workaround so that you iterate through a property of the instance, you could create a method to increment it, change your loop to a `Do While ... Loop` and call that method before the loop call.

```
'Class Module
Option Explicit

Public i As Integer

Public Sub increment_i()
i = i + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
i = 0
End Sub
```

---

```
'Module
Sub loop_myclass()

Dim instance As MyClass: Set instance = New MyClass

Do While instance.i <= 10
'Instance property dependent code here
    Debug.Print instance.i
    instance.increment_i
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a publicly accessible loop variable stick it at the top of a standard module i.e. declare the Public i at the top of a standard module.

Note that this would mean you need to re-write your standard module code as, as per point two, you are treating i as if it is a property/method of the class.

So, standard module code would be:

```
Public i As Long

Sub ........

   For i = 1 To 10
       Debug.Print "Hello"
   Next i

End Sub ......
```

If you want it to somehow be a property/method then you need to define  Getters and Setters (potentially) in the class. And then re-write your module code accordingly. Especially if you are planning on looping using i, you will need an incrementor method in the class.

And yes, I have changed i to Long as there are no advantages, in this case I believe, of having it declared as Integer. A Long is a safer bet for avoiding potential overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use MyInstance.i as the increment counter but you can use it as the terminator; e.g. For i = 1 To MyInstance.i.

MyClass class

```
Option Explicit

Public pi As Long

Public Property Get i() As Long
    i = pi
End Property

Public Property Let i(Value As Long)
    pi = Value
End Property
```

test sub procedure in Module1

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyInstance As MyClass, i As Long
    Set MyInstance = New MyClass
    MyInstance.i = 10
    For i = 1 To MyInstance.i
        Debug.Print "Hello"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool. + 1. Can you not also use it as the start?

Comment: Sure! As long as it isn't the increment. Seeing my class page bounce into the foreground as I F8'ed through that probably has something to do with the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer. There is [a Microsoft help page on For…Next loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement#BKMK_Counter) regarding VB, but I think it pertains to VBA as well.

It says:

> If the scope of `counter` isn't local to the procedure, a compile-time
>   warning occurs.

So there's not much to discuss here, it's just the way MS wants it to be. Though I'd think that if the scope is greater than the procedure it shouldn't cause any problems, but apparently it does.